# how to couple 2 male ends of a weed wacker?

Tags: powertools, lawn

I have a weed whacker and a corresponding attachment that goes with it. I'm trying to attach the two but I found that my weed whacker has an inverted configuration that most other weed whackers don't have.

instead of providing a female adapter from the power head, it's male, and it's inverted all the way down to the wire. The attachment that I want to use, a pole saw, starts with a male attachment and ends with a female attachment down at the saw.

reading online, the reason for the weed wacker head being inverted is so that competitors attachments can't be used. I say to hell with that.

the attachment point of the whacker head (fits the power head currently):
[image]

the attachment point of the pole saw head (does not fit power head):
[image]

I'm essentially looking for a way to couple the pole saw had such that it more closely resembles the wacker head. however, Even though the star shaped female receiver seems to be universal across all attachments, I cannot find a coupler anywhere online.

My question is does such a thing exist and if so what is it called?

Comment: It looks like the female "star" will accept the square drive...or I'm just not understanding the whole thing..

Comment: @RMDman what you're looking at is two different attachments that would go on to the power head. The power head is male so it will not fit pictured pole saw, because it is male. but in the first picture the weed eater attachment is female so it will fit the power head

Comment: Ok...thanks...it's clearer to me now...but I can't help you.

Comment: All good. Been noodling over this for a few days now.

Comment: Stuff like this is not good to modify, because of the speed if it does not stay on.  Pole saws and weed whackers don't seem to go together, I know of circular saw blade attachments for weed whackers.

Comment: @crip659 there's a good number of companies that make these pole saw attachments. I think they're worm driven, not 100% sure. anyway, it's why I'm asking here